# Haproxy backend with SSL unable to talk to Istio Mesh

Tags: kubernetes, istio, haproxy

I am new with Kubernetes and need some help.

I am running an Istio mesh where all my services are using mtls. These are grpc service. Here is my PeerAuthentication inside the namespace:

```
    apiVersion: security.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: PeerAuthentication
metadata:
  name: "default"
  namespace: db1

spec:
  mtls:
    mode: STRICT
```

Here are my services:

```
 ➜  ~ kubectl -n db1 get svc
NAME                      TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)              AGE
db1                ClusterIP   10.100.114.234   <none>        19530/TCP,9091/TCP   62m
```

My pods inside the mesh are running fine and can talk.
I want a Haproxy which is in different namespace and outside the mesh to talk with my db1 service.

As the db1 is a grpc service, I have this Haproxy config:

```
global
    log stdout format raw local0 info
    maxconn 1024
    
  defaults
    log global
    mode http
    timeout client 60s
    timeout connect 60s
    timeout server 60s


  frontend fe_main
    
    bind *:19530 proto h2
    mode http
    
    http-request capture req.hdr(Host) len 100
  
      
    default_backend be_db1
  
  backend be_db1
    mode http 
    server-template db1-milvus 1 db1.db1.svc.cluster.local:19530 check proto h2 ssl verify none crt /etc/certs/shared/db1_haproxy_certs.pem
```

I don't see any request is going to my db1 service from the Haproxy. However, if I disable MTLs inside the Istio mesh and remove the ssl crt part in Haproxy, I do see successful connection.

What am I missing in my Haproxy ssl config?
Please advice.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The [FAQ here](https://istio.io/latest/about/faq/security/#non-istio-to-istio) covers your question. Basically, you can't have STRICT mTLS enabled as the non-mesh workloads won't have a valid Istio workload certificate.

One of the solutions is to enable PERMISSIVE mode in this case.